# Particle notation: What does the asterisk stand for?

Tags: particle-physics, standard-model, notation

For instance, what's the difference between $\Sigma^0$ particles and $\Sigma^{0*}$ particles? I know they have the same quark configuration $sdu$, so how exactly are they different?

Some context: I'm reading the 2nd chapter of Halzen's *Quarks and Leptons*. I found the sigma baryons (with and without the asterisk) on Figure 2.8. More precisely, I found the $\Sigma$ particles on the spin 1/2 graph, and the $\Sigma^*$ particles on the spin 3/2 graph.

Comment: Star superscripts can mean different things in different context. I suspect that "excited state" and "off-shell" are the most common meanings, but without some more data people will be shooting in the dark.

Comment: @dmckee thanks for the quick comment. I'm just starting out with the study of the quark model. For example, in the electromagnetic decay $\Sigma^*(1385)^- \rightarrow \Sigma^- \gamma$, I wonder what (1385) means (I guess it's the mass) and what the star/asterisk means. Perhaps there's still more context needed, but thank you anyway.

Comment: Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/341422/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In case of the $\Sigma$ particles the $^*$ means "excited" (i.e. having a higher energy, thus a higher rest mass). 
For other particles the $^*$ may have other meanings
(see the posted comments below).

According to Wikipedia "[Sigma baryon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sigma_baryon)":

The $\Sigma^{0*}$ baryon has total angular momentum $J=\frac{3}{2}$ and rest mass $1383\text{ MeV}/c^2$.
The $\Sigma^0$ baryon has total angular momentum $J=\frac{1}{2}$ and rest mass $1192\text{ MeV}/c^2$.

Each quark ($u$, $d$ and $s$) has a spin angular momentum of $\frac{1}{2}$.
Grossly simplified you can imagine the particles like this:

- In the $\Sigma^{0*}$ baryon all 3 quarks are spinning in the same sense,
  giving a total angular momentum of
  $\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2}=\frac{3}{2}$.
- In the $\Sigma^0$ baryon 2 quarks are spinning in one sense,
  and 1 quark is spinning in the opposite sense,
  giving a total angular momentum of
  $\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{2}=\frac{1}{2}$.

Explaining why $\Sigma^{0*}$ has a higher energy than $\Sigma^0$
would be a more difficult story.

Comment: For mesons, such as $K^*, D^*$,... the asterisk denotes vector as opposed to spinless mesons lacking the asterisk...

Comment: 1. You can have excited states without the star. 2. Scalar flavoured mesons (as opposed to pseudoscalars) have stars, e.g. the $K^*_0(1430)$.

Answer (score 1):

In the PDG notation, a star is not synonymous with an excited state. Yes, any state with a star is excited, but not all excited states have a star. It depends on the spin and parity.

From the [PDG naming scheme for hadrons](http://pdg.lbl.gov/2018/reviews/rpp2018-rev-naming-scheme-hadrons.pdf) in the section on flavoured mesons:

> 3. If the spin-parity is in the "normal" series, $J^P = 0^+, 1^-, 2^+,...$, a superscript "$^*$" is added.

In other words, the star tells you the parity is positive for even spin and negative for odd.

They don't seem to define rules for starred baryons, and the only one I can find is the $\Sigma_b^*$.